Getting error while authenticating using arcana sdk
enter image description here,Getting this error while authenticating
here is the code for authenticationenter image description here,
I have gone as per the documentation. Not sure what is wrong
I got an error as mentioned above while authenticating

Code excerpts and error-messages are best pasted into the question, rather than shown as screen-dumps. That way, they're easier for people to read and easier to find when searching. Please edit the question to replace the images with text, delimited by triple-back-ticks.
